# Como obter diferença de horas entre duas variáveis DateTime em C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Tenho duas variáveis `DateTime`, que são DataCadastro e `DataAtual(DateTime.Now)`. Preciso saber se a diferença de horas entre estas duas datas é maior ou igual a 4 horas. Existe algum método na classe `DateTime` que atenda essa minha exigência? Ou preciso de outra alternativa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você precisa usar [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) para isso.

Exemplo:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dt1 = DateTime.Now;
        var dt2 = new DateTime(2015, 09, 22, 00, 50, 00);

        TimeSpan ts = dt1 - dt2;

        WriteLine($"Diferença em horas {ts.TotalHours}");
        WriteLine($"Diferença em minutos {ts.TotalMinutes}");
        WriteLine($"Diferença em dias {ts.TotalDays}");            
        WriteLine($"Diferença maior que 4 horas: {ts.TotalHours >= 4}");
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WDaAeA)

Answer (score 5):

É bem simples:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var data1 = DateTime.Now;
        var data2 = new DateTime(2015, 9, 23);
        WriteLine($"Diferença: {data1 - data2}");
        WriteLine($"Mais que 4 horas: {data1 - data2 >= new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0)}");
        WriteLine($"Mais que 4 horas (outra forma): {(data1 - data2).TotalHours >= 4}");
        WriteLine($"Mais que 4 horas (se primeira pode ser anterior): {Math.Abs((data2 - data1).TotalHours) >= 4}");
        WriteLine($"Mais que 4 horas (se primeira é anterior): {-(data2 - data1).TotalHours >= 4}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LcQR1A). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mv2xFo). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Difference2.cs).